# Can I selectively amend or replace types of methods in interfaces in third-party modules in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using `immutable.js` in my Typescript project, and it provides incorrect declarations for some of its methods. For example, the `Indexed<T>` method `get` is declared as returning `T`, but in practice it returns `T | undefined`, and I want to amend that type in my own project so I can use it without having to fork immutable.js.

I tried putting this in one of modules (not an ambient .d.ts, because I learned that apparently you can't augment third-party interfaces unless you're in a module).

```
declare module 'immutable' {
  export interface Iterable<K, V> {
    get(key: K, notSetValue?: V): V | undefined;
  }
  export interface Indexed<T> extends Iterable<number, T> {
    get(index: number, notSetValue?: T): T | undefined;
  }
}
```

(Indexed extends Iterable which provides a similar `get` method, so I had to extend it).

Here's the error I'm getting when I try this code:

```
ERROR in c:\...\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable-nonambient.d.ts
(1260,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Indexed<T>' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Seq<number, T>' and 'Indexed<T>'.
  Named property 'get' of types 'Seq<number, T>' and 'Indexed<T>' are not identical.

ERROR in c:\...\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable-nonambient.d.ts
(2486,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Indexed<T>' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Collection<number, T>' and 'Indexed<T>'.
  Named property 'get' of types 'Collection<number, T>' and 'Indexed<T>' are not identical.
```

These errors are confusing to me, because Collection and Seq don't explicitly have `get` methods declared in the immutable.d.ts file -- they simply extend Iterable.

Interestingly, I *do* get type errors in some other code that I have that is calling `get()` and not handling the `undefined`, so it looks like typescript has picked up that I'm amending the Immutable module's declarations and applying those rules elsewhere; I just can't get this declaration itself to compile since it seems to be confused about unifying with the original Iterable declaration.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why I don't contribute a change to Immutable.js: I want to, just waiting for confirmation from the devs. I just want to get my code working in the meantime: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/1238